# Upload file with GitHub action instead of folder

Tags: github, github-actions, artifacts

I use [`actions/upload-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) to upload artifacts after a successful workflow run like this:

```
   path: |
     path/to/firstbin.app
     path/to/secondbin.dmg
```

The binaries are stored in `bundle/app/firstbin.app` and `bundle/dmg/secondbin.dmg`. GHA uploads the bundle folder.
So I get a useless folder in the artifact file.
How to upload only these two files?

Comment: it is listed in the readme on how to do single files https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#usage if `bundle/app/firstbin` is a folder but you don't want the folder then don't move the folder :/ target the file only `bundle/app/firstbin/file.ext`

Comment: I update my post. `firstbin` and `secondbin` are files, not folder

Comment: cool, so then replace `path/to/firstbin` with `bundle/app/firstbin.app`

Comment: It's already that I do

Comment: can you clarify *useless folder*? so you are moving the whole folder but only want single packaged files within that folder but you're already only targeting the file but its moving the whole folder? it would help if you added real paths and perhaps a screen or text output of what you're getting.

Comment: Bundle have a sub folder which is uploaded

Comment: Log : https://github.com/Ludea/Sparus/actions/runs/3719990504/jobs/6309195531#step:8:11

Comment: see: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#zipped-artifact-downloads seems whats happening is due to zipping it, since you pass the full path `${{ fromJSON(steps.build.outputs.artifactPaths)[0] }}` it will maintain the paths which include the dmg/macos folders, what you could try is move the files you want to a tmp location first, then just add that single folder

Comment: I can't move file into tmp folder. I if I do that, I have to specify the folder I want to upload and it's not compatible with github matrix host. The binaries are retrieve by previous step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#zipped-artifact-downloads) clearly states that *"if multiple paths are provided as input, the least common ancestor of all the search paths will be used as the root directory of the artifact."* Therefore, you need to either avoid specifying multiple paths or copy the files to a flattened staging directory.

You can upload two files to the same artifact like this:

```
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
         name: first/abc/firstbin.app
         path: 
         if-no-files-found: error
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
         name: second/xyz/firstbin.dmg
         path: 
         if-no-files-found: error
```

Be careful when uploading to the same artifact and read the relevant [documentation](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#uploading-to-the-same-artifact).